# Set event handler on arbitrary JS function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'd like to write a Chrome extension that works with a particular JS-based chat application. It needs to be made aware every time the chat receives a message.

Now, I can obviously do this easily by setting up a timer and checking to see if `$("chat-messages").childElements().length` has increased, but I'd rather go with the more elegant method of setting up an event handler of some sort to fire every time `appendChatMessage()` is invoked. Is there a way to do this?

```
var oldfunc = appendChatMessage;
appendChatMessage = function() { eval(oldfunc); myChatMessageReceivedHandler(); }
```

Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Should this be tagged as `jquery`??

Comment: @Kerrek: It doesn't have much to do with jQuery, but I've retagged it since it is available, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldfunc = appendChatMessage;
appendChatMessage = function() { eval(oldfunc(); myChatMessageReceivedHandler(); }
```

Should work, depending on the context.

Comment: This works on my own functions, but throws the following when I try it on a chat function:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: woops! Silly me. I forgot to sent oldfunc() the arguments it needed.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a method `appendChatMessage` that is called every time a new message arrives, you could do like this

```
var old = appendChatMessage;
appendChatMessage = function() {
    // call the initial method and store the result
    var result = old.apply( this, arguments );

    // do your stuff here

    // return the initial result
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do `oldfunc()`. Besides that I'd create an event to to that

```
var oldfunc = appendChatMessage;
appendChatMessage = function() { oldfunc(); $(document).trigger("msg_received"); }

$(document).bind("msg_received", function(params){
   //do your logic when message arrives
});
```

You should decide which element to attach the event into and its params.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = function () { console.log('foo'); }

var f2 = f;

f = function () { f2(); console.log('bar'); }
```

This should print:

`foo`

`bar`